Why any Muslim majority country do not have veto power in UN?
No Muslim majority country have veto power. I suspect, this is a systematic plan to destroy Islam (meaning peace) from the world. Now we can see that the countries who have veto power are living in peace and all the war is happening in rest of world.
I think giving veto power to few countries which has Muslim majority can create peace in the world.

"the countries who have veto power are living in peace" - you mean apart from Russia?

There are only five countries with the veto power. Have you looked at the history of the UN, UNSC and the veto power? Unclear how that doesn't answer the headline question.

Im sorry but
'I suspect, this is a systematic plan to destroy Islam (meaning peace) from the world. '
Is just conspiratorial. I have to DV this.
One only needs to take a short and simple look ate the history of the UN, to know the reason and therefore this question shows NO sign of having looked into it oneself.

Shafeek your posting history has a bunch of questions which have been closed or significantly down-voted because they seem to lack even cursory research and exist mostly to promote your own views. This is another. The only question is in the heading. The text is just your personal theories. Please stop posting this kind of question.

@PaulJohnson They won't. I know this kind of user, they're too far gone to listen to anything other than immediate and vociferous agreement with everything they say. Trying to engage with them in good faith is a waste of time because they're not here to engage in good faith themselves. Just downvote, flag, and move on.

UN is supposed to be neutral. It is hard to be neutral when religion is in the mind, and even harder when that religion has active extremist branches.

@user13964273  Thats not the reasoning, becuase there IS no reasoning. Nobody made the activ edecision to exclude Muslim countries, since the veto countries was just the great powers club. Besides none of the countries that have veto powers are neutral

@SMSTJ Isn't it possible that exactly religion was the reason why no Muslim counties had that "great power"...? "Trusting in the sanity and restraint of Muslim countries is not an option, is not a strategy! Let's bomb them to the ground." (BTW, single countries are not supposed to be neutral, it is UNO as whole.)

@user13964273  Being Muslim was not the reason that they where not a great power. The graetest of the Muslim powers was the Ottomans, which siezed to be after WW1 and then under Attürk underwent a major Secularazation programme. Also most places with a high Muslim concentration where Colonies by the time the UNSC was established. Sure you had your Iraqs,Iran and Afganistan, but they where hardly great powers at the time. Religion was never a thing considered by anyone during the UNSC establishment

On religion its also worth noting that the UK is Protestant, the USA is complicated (the original settlers were there because they rejected the UK church) but nominally secular, France is historically Catholic but nominally secular, China is historically Confucian but at the time was officially atheist, and Russia is historically Orthodox but at the time was also officially atheist. The idea that these 5 got together and said "The number 1 priority is to exclude the Muslims" is ridiculous.

And who would that be, exactly?  The 5 present members didn't exactly get in via a vote of enthused supporters, they got in because they badgered their way in on their own, had just booted Hitler or horse-traded among each other.  This hypothetically redemptive Muslim nation, which one would it be?  Iran?  Saudi Arabia?  Turkey?  Indonesia? You can bet that most of the others would bitterly complain on not being chosen.  If it makes you feel any better, India often claims dibs on expansion...

The Wikipedia page on the veto power describes the history.
Briefly, when the UN was set up at the end of World War II, the four "great powers" (UK, US, China, Russia) refused to sign up to the UN Charter unless they got veto power. Since a UN that omitted one of these powers would be meaningless, they got their way. France was also included as a Permanent Member with veto power at a later stage.
So this isn't some kind of anti-Muslim agenda. Rather, it reflects the geopolitical situation in the late 1940s when all this was agreed. Had one of the great powers happened to be Muslim (lets say, the Ottoman Empire had survived into the 1940s) then it would doubtless have been included.
As to the prospects for the UN and world peace if more countries were given veto power, it seems unlikely. The League of Nations was the UN predecessor, and that gave all its members veto power. The result was simply paralysis: nothing could be agreed because there was always someone willing to exercise a veto. The current situation is not ideal: nothing can be done against any Permanent Member or their allies. But its the best we have in the current world.

I really appreciate you taking the time to answer this, however I think this is just encuraging the posting of further low quality question like this.
Still a UV though


giving veto power to few countries which has Muslim majority can create peace in the world.

How exactly? I can see that they might have vetoed the 1990 Gulf war--YMMV as many Muslim countries were actually in the coalition against Iraq--, but many wars since then were not a result of a UNSC collective decision, and the veto power was useless in preventing [most of] those wars from starting.
N.B. the creation of Israel as such didn't go through the UNSC, as far as I can tell, but only through UNGA. And those resolutions are not technically binding. Possibly a Muslim UNSC veto would have delayed or even completely forestalled UN membership for Israel, but whether that would have made the world more peaceful, YMMV again, since de-facto states have existed for decades even in the absence of formal UN recognition, especially when they have powerful allies. The two Koreas, for example, were not admitted to the UN until the 1990s!
Yeah, if one is willing to engage in more speculation, perhaps Israel's supporters would have been willing to trade Israel's admission to the UN for Palestine's membership. That kind of horse trading happened with respect to some Soviet bloc countries and some 'counterparts' more aligned with the West. (And the veto power in the UNSC played a central role in those deals.) Whether the simple fact of UN membership for Palestine would have resulted in [more] peace (at least in that region) is again a matter of further speculation. Border disagreements could have still led to wars etc.


Now we can see that the countries who have veto power are living in peace

Those countries have nuclear weapons. And Russia is not exactly 'living in peace' at the moment, albeit many (surely most in the West) would say Russia started the latest war involving them.

BTW, for the history buffs, Turkey might have had a chance of being on better terms with the Allies at end of WW2 (and so in the post-WW2 world order), had it entered the war [on the side of the Allies], but the Turkish government was very cautious especially in the early stage of the war, when the victor was hardly clear (they even agreed in 1942 to sell chrome to Germany, which was a vital raw material for the arms industry), and ultimately the Allies, especially the USSR were not too keen on Turkey's participation (esp. later on), e.g. after Churchill made some public 'invitation' in Aug 1944:

the Soviet Union was very reserved, and there were open statements in Pravda and Izvestia, along with continued attacks, that Turkish entry into the war would serve no useful purpose and was no longer desired
[...]
The United States held firmly to the view that the knockout blow against Germany was to be delivered in the West and was not disposed to divert supplies to any secondary front. This is clear from the discussions at Quebec, Moscow, Tehran and Cairo, where even Mr. Churchill indicated that he would settle for “strained neutrality” on Turkey’s part. Despite all the talk and propaganda to the contrary, the Soviet Government and Premier Stalin do not appear much interested in Turkey’s active participation, as noted particularly at Tehran because of (1) the priority of Operation OVERLORD which “must come first;” (2) the Soviet objection to Turkish or other non-Soviet forces in the Balkans ; (3) the Soviet desire for concessions at the Straits and elsewhere in Turkey; (4) the Soviet objection to Turkish representation at a post-war peace conference; and (5) the Soviet desire to “talk” and make propaganda out of Turkey’s nonparticipation in the “shooting war.”


Last sentence is like that because I'm aware many in the 'global south', and some Muslims in particular disagree.

Speaking of the Gulf War, it's interesting to note who led the Arab armies then, and what other wars they were engaged in since https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khalid_bin_Sultan_Al_Saud#Career

Finally, the OP might have operated under some wrong assumptions about some such (putative) Isalmic prohibitions https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/84670/are-soldiers-sinning-when-they-kill-enemy-in-a-war
